# Mongodb Permission validation failed

Tags: php, mongodb

I can be successful through remote access mongodb. use this :

```
try {
    $mon = new MongoClient('mongodb://user:user@121.21.147.245:27017');
}catch(MongoConnectionException $e) {
    exit("Failed to connect to database :". iconv('GB2312','UTF-8', $e->getMessage()));
}
```

But I put the procedure and mongodb the same server, the link again suggested that the authority is not correct.

```
try {
    $mon = new MongoClient('mongodb://user:user@121.21.147.245:27017');
}catch(MongoConnectionException $e) {
    exit("Failed to connect to database :". iconv('GB2312','UTF-8', $e->getMessage()));
}
```

Using the local address nor

```
try {
    $mon = new MongoClient('mongodb://user:user@127.0.0.1:27017');
}catch(MongoConnectionException $e) {
    exit("Failed to connect to database :". iconv('GB2312','UTF-8', $e->getMessage()));
}
```

Prompt this error

```
Failed to connect to database :
Failed to connect to: 121.21.147.245:27017: 
Authentication failed on database    'admin' with username 'user': auth failed

Failed to connect to database :
Failed to connect to: 127.0.0.1:27017: 
Authentication failed on database    'admin' with username 'user': auth failed
```

Why remote connections can be used, but not local?

Comment: Have you tried to add connect DB in your connection string. Like this 'mongodb://user:user@127.0.0.1:27017/dbYouWouldLikeToConnect?' . Mongo users often allowed to connect to specific DB.. So your user cant access admin DB that's why you got error.

Comment: So why do I connect to the database through a remote server there is no problem? 'mongodb: / / user: user@127.0.0.1: 27017'